# Align text node centrally(horizontally) inside group element

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have this group element and a text node inside it:

```
var legend = svg_container.append('g');
var legend_text = legend.append('text').attr('y', 0)
//other elements inside 'g'
```

This is just part of the code. In actuality, I have other child nodes inside the group element created on the fly after the text node(these other elements decide the width of the group element).

How do I position the text node centrally inside the group element?

Comment: Can you inspect the resulting `html`? Maybe post it here?

Comment: I'll add a screenshot. Will that do?

Comment: Nope. In the end, it all comes down to html and css, no matter how complex or advanced the logic behind the app. :)

Comment: first get the .getBBox(); of g it will give the x y width and hieght....now set the text's x to bbox.x + bbox+bbox.width/2 and y to bbox.y +bbox.height/2

Answer (score 2):

To center it, you can use the text attribute `text-anchor="middle"`  with the `x` and `y` attributes for positioning:

```
legend_text.attr("text-anchor","middle");
legend_text.attr("x", 0);
legend_text.attr("y", 0);
```

Here, your text will be fixed to the center origin of your group `legend`.

In fact, it won't be perfectly centered, to do so, you should set `y` to the half of the `font-size` attribute of your text.

Hoping I've correctly understood your problem !

EDIT: With your indication, I see two solutions :

- My favorite one would include a modification of the `legend` group, by adding him a `transform="translate(x,y)"` attribute,
  where the x and y are the center of your svg element. This one may not work with the rest of your code, but I find that doing so in general is a clean way to have multiple drawings living together in a single svg.
- The other one is simplier by far, and I think will answer to your problem for now :

  You replace the `x` and `y` values by the center of your `legend` group. The little problem here is the calculation of thoses values, because you can't read them directly from the element.

In fact, a `g` element doesn't have width or height attributes, it's only a container for applying attributes for a group of `svg` elements. That's why I recommend using my first solution.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I want it aligned centered horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of centering it in the group using `bbox`

```
//make a g
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", "900")
  .attr("height", "900").append("g");
//add circle to it
svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 50).attr("cy", 50).attr("r", 30);
svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 250).attr("cy", 150).attr("r", 30);
//get bbox
var bb = svg.node().getBBox();
var centery = bb.y + bb.height/2;
var centerx = bb.x + bb.width/2;

svg.append("text").text("Hello").attr("x",centerx).attr("y", centery)
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/g04hLt5q/1/)

Comment: I am appending the text before adding other elements as mentioned in the question.

Comment: ahh missed that in this case it will not wrk...as group will have no width and height initially when there is no element in it...may be you can update the text position every time an element is added or removed from group just a suggestion.